# How to auto redirect user to Default.aspx if they directly access any page of website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

[image]

I have the following pages structure in my asp.net 3.5 website ...

i want if anybody directly access any page of my site as http://mysite.com/cancellation.aspx then it will automatically redirected to http://mysite.com/Default.aspx

How to do this using vb.net, asp.net

Comment: How is anyone supposed to get to and see `cancellation.aspx` if you always redirect to `Default.aspx`?

Comment: I want if user directly access cancellation.aspx.... then only redirect to Default.aspx other wise ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `session` value in your webapplication for cancellation.aspx. This state value must set before only cancllation.aspx (it could be confirmation.aspx).
In other case cancellation.aspx never load.

`Page_load` for cancellation.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(Session["stateValu"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if either you are using "Form Authentication" or checking user with authentication.

This is form authentication which is used in web.config.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="frm" loginUrl="login.aspx">
        <credentials>
          <user name="" password=""/>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Or you can check authentication in Master page (if using) or each page. If failed then redirect it.